# JavaParser: How do I add a method call to a chained invocation?

Tags: java, javaparser

Given a chained invocation (builder pattern):

```java
return new ThingBuilder().withA(a).withB(b).build();
```

How can I use JavaParser to add another chained invocation to end up with code like this:

```java
return new ThingBuilder().withA(a).withB(b).withC(c).build();
```

I'm already familiar with the `ModifierVisitor`, but am unable to find a good way to add the call in the right place, i.e to the relevant `MethodCallExpr` (the one where the expression is `new ThingBuilder().withA(a).withB(b)` and the method is `build()`).

It would be fine to add it at the top level too if that's possible:

```java
return new ThingBuilder().withC(c).withA(a).withB(b).build();
```

Comment: I will settle for an answer like "this is the least gross way of doing this"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work:

```java
    @Override
    public Visitable visit(final MethodCallExpr n, final Void arg) {
        final Visitable visit = super.visit(n, arg);
        if (!n.getName().getIdentifier().equals("build")) {
            return visit;
        }
        n.getScope()
                .filter(Expression::isMethodCallExpr)
                .map(Expression::asMethodCallExpr)
                .filter(method -> method.getName().getIdentifier().equals("withB"))
                .ifPresent(method -> {
                    final Node leftSide = n.getChildNodes().get(0);
                    final Optional<Expression> scope = n.getScope();
                    final MethodCallExpr withC = new MethodCallExpr("withC", new NameExpr("c"));
                    leftSide.replace(withC);
                    scope.ifPresent(withC::setScope);
                });
        return visit;
    }
```

I'd be happy to learn if there's a more elegant way to do this.